NASM Integration with VS2022 for Windows
Can anybody help me with integration of NASM with VS2022 on Windows , I am confused I am not able to find the solution , and official NASM website doesn't have an Docs on how to integrate it with VS 2022, can somebody help me to integrate it with VS2022

You need to create a custom build step. Is there a reason you are not using MASM (32 bit or 64 bit), which is included with VS2022?

I have been familiar with FASM and NASM and wanted to work with NASM in VS2022 and to be honest I haven't worked with MASM , so that's the reason , but I would like to try MASM as well , but for now I want to integrate NASM in VS2022

This answer, shows how to setup Visual Studio for MASM. Should be similar for NASM. Create an empty console project, copy source file into the project, then from VS2022, click on project, and "add existing item".

I will try this , thanks bro
